# Windows: unblocking app from accessing network

Tags: windows-7, windows

I use linux for the most part and I am not very familiar with Windows. While working on a machine that runs Windows 7, I made a silly mistake and now I do not know how to revert the operation.

Do you know those pop-ups that warn the user when an application is trying to access the network? I believe I ended up denying access to the network and I may have clicked the box that was telling windows not to ask me the same question again. How can I revert the operation and allow the application to access the network again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Allow a program through Windows Firewall.

Then tick the box for the relevent program and connection permissions